# Android: Debug which UI element under touch, focus etc

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-xml

I have very complex layout xml (1K+ code rows). When I perform under testing some input (touch, click, swipe...) I want to know what happens: Which elements under focus, which elements got click events etc.

I tried under developer options to enable show layout bounds & show touches. But it's not what I'm looking for. Also I want to avoid solution of Log prints on entry to `View` methods, Because I think must be a more direct method.

EDIT - This app dev environment is still Eclipse.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) of the Android Studio Tools. It work fine for your purpose.

If you are using the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) in any other way, you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) that you can find the same [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) from the SDK `tools/` directory, entering to `monitor`.

Comment: Thanks! But I have some issue - from some reasons it's still eclipse ADT... Is there some equivalent tool?

Comment: I've edited the question for other uses of the Android SDK, I think that could work for your case too :)